# How should I implement the cascade of classifiers in Viola-Jones algorithm on FPGA?

Tags: fpga, viola-jones

I am trying to implement the Viola-Jones algorithm on FPGA. I am not sure what I should do about the cascade of classifiers. How should I implement it on the FPGA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2468067216300116), seems exactly what you're looking for. You'll need a handle on VHDL or some hardware-description-language as well as some sort of breakout board like the Altera they are using.

[Project Files and Source Code](http://dejazzer.com/hardware.html)